# one2many field stores only last record when fill

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

please help me regarding one2many field in odoo12.
firstly, sorry for bad grammar.

i am getting products from invoice_line_ids of account.invoice model.
but when i store these products in my custom model only last record is stored in one2many field in my class.
here is my code.

```
invoice_report = self.create(vals)
product_dict={}
product_list=[]

for line in ids.invoice_line_ids:
    product_dict.update({
        'product_name':line.product_id.name,
        'qty':line.quantity,
        'unit_price':line.price_unit,
        'tax':line.invoice_line_tax_ids.name or "",
        'subtotal':line.price_subtotal
    })

    product_list.append([(1,invoice_report.id,product_dict)])

for data in product_list:
    invoice_report.write({
        'inv_products':data
    })
```

inv_products is my one2many field
invoice_report is my recently created record. i.e custom.invoice(1,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [x2many values filling](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L3257), the format you used updates an existing record of id `id` with the values in `values`. `id` should be an id of an `inv_products` record, not a `custom.invoice` record.

You should receive an Odoo server error in case record with id equal to `1` does not exist in the database:

```
One of the records you are trying to modify has already been deleted (Document type: custom.report.line).

(Records: (1,), User: 2)
```

You declared `product_dict` outside a for loop and you used `update` inside, at the end of the loop you will have the values of the last line of `invoice_line_ids` repeated, You asked the system to update a specific line (with id invoice_report.id) with the same values in each iteration when you called `write` method.

To add new records to `inv_products`, use `[(0, 0, values)]` format:

```
invoice_report = self.create(vals)
product_list = []

for line in ids.invoice_line_ids:
    product_dict = {

    }

    product_list.append((0, 0, product_dict))

invoice_report.write({
    'inv_products': product_list
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. and sorry i can not up vote your answer due to less than 15 reputation.